# Using recursion inside a called constructor

Tags: c++11, recursion, constructor

Don't know where to begin on how to use recursion within a called constructor.

recursion.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#include "MinilabRecursion.h"

MinilabRecursion::puzzleRecurse(int n)
    {
        int recurse(n) // <--- Don't know what to do here
        {      //error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
            if( n == 0 )
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if( n >= 1 )
            {
                return recurse(n - 1) + 4 * n;
            }
        }
    }          //error: expected '}' at end of input
```

driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "MinilabRecursion.h"
{
        cout << "puzzleRecurse(1) returns: " << MinilabRecursion::puzzleRecurse(1) << endl;

        cout << "puzzleRecurse(7) returns: " << MinilabRecursion::puzzleRecurse(7) << endl;

        cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

recursion.h

```
#ifndef MINILABRECURSION_H
#define MINILABRECURSION_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MinilabRecursion
{
public:
    static int puzzleFormula(int n);
    static int puzzleLoop(int n);
    static int puzzleRecurse(int n);
};
#endif
```

The if statements within recursion.cpp should give me the desired outcome, but I do not know how to use recursion in this context.

Comment: "within a called constructor." What constructor? I'm not seeing any constructor here.

Comment: I don't know the term for it. Starting from "MinilabRecursion::puzzleRecurse(int n)" within recursion.cpp is where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I can make sense out of the code you posted. It seems you want to do the following, but are confused about some of the C++ basics:

```
int MinilabRecursion::puzzleRecurse(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return puzzleRecurse(n - 1) + 4 * n;
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct; I am very confused about the basics of C++, so tt's difficult for me to word my questions. What you posted helped me. Thanks for your time.